# How do i use Update function in Controller --resources just for $request?

Tags: laravel, parameters, routes

I'm currently trying to update record using update in controller
--resource but it doesnt allow me to use `$request` parameter only. I'm 
following a tutorial and it work for him.

I tried removing the `$id` in parameter
in my blade.php :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "{{ route('courses.update') }}",
    method:"POST",
```

in my controllers it looks like this:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $rules = array(
        'description' => 'required',
        'college'  => 'required'
    );

    $formD = array(
        'description' => $request->description,
        'college' => $request->college
```

and in my Routes;

```
Route::resource('courses', 'CourseController');
```

Comment: which tutorial are you following?

Comment: can you please post the full controller code

Comment: Webslesson. how can i post it here?

Comment: i just used --resource when i created the controller